# How to automatically create relationship between user model and custom group in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

As a newbie to Django, all things are still not clear to me. I'm having some issues while working on my project. Whenever I register as a new student, it lets me to login. But I cannot upload profile picture. It throws me an error:

```
ValueError at /account_settings/
The 'profile_pic' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

When I login as an admin and want to see the new student, I just see a blank space, not the new student. Here is the screenshot of my admin view: [image: Student name is blank]

If I see from admin page, there is also a blank space. Here is admin page view:
[image: Blank space]

I have to manually create a student and an user from admin page, and make relationship between them. Please anyone explain me what actually happens behind the scenario. I'm a noob, I'll be grateful if anyone kindly makes it clear for me. Thanks in advance.

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default= 'default-picture.jpg', null= True, blank= True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Books(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
            ('Physics', 'Physics'),
            ('Chemistry', 'Chemistry'),
            ('Mathematics', 'Mathematics'),
            ) 

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Issue(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
            ('Pending', 'Pending'),
            ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
            ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
            )

    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Books, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.book.name
```

Here is my forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Issue
from .models import Student

class IssueForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = '__all__'
        

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class StudentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user']
```

It's my decorators.py file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def unauthenticated_user(func):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


def allowed_user(allowed_roles=[]):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            group = None
            if request.user.groups.exists():
                group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
            
            if group in allowed_roles:
                return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('You are not authorized to view this page.')  
        return wrapper
    return decorator


def admin_only(func):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = None

        if request.user.groups.exists():
            group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
        
        if group == 'Student':
            return redirect ('user_page')
        else:
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        
    return wrapper
```

It's my `registration`, `login` and `account_setting` method in views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import *
from .forms import IssueForm, CreateUserForm, StudentForm
from .filters import IssueFilter
from .decorators import unauthenticated_user, allowed_user, admin_only

@unauthenticated_user
def registerPage(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user =form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')

            group = Group.objects.get(name = 'Student')
            user.groups.add(group)
            Student.objects.create(
                user = user
            )

            messages.success(request, 'Account successfully created for ' + username)
            return redirect ('login')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)


@unauthenticated_user
def loginPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect ('home')
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'Username or Password is incorrect')
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')


@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_user(allowed_roles=['Student'])
def accountSettings(request):
    user = request.user.student
    form = StudentForm(instance=user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/account_settings.html', context)
```

And my account_seetings.html template:

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content%}

<style>
    .profile-pic{
        max-width: 300px;
        max-height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 70%;
    }
</style>

<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'home' %}"> &#8592; Back to Profile</a>

            <hr>
            <img class="profile-pic" src="{{request.user.student.profile_pic.url}}">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form.as_p}}
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="Update Information">
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

It should be noted that I have two `groups` in admin page. These are `Student` and `Admin`.

Comment: I see  User as ```OneToOneField```  on Student model. Are users registering first before they can be added as students?

Comment: This User is Django's default user model. And I want a OneToOne relationship between user and student after it is created.